# Setting transparency in irrlicht scene

Tags: ios, ios7, irrlicht

I had working in iPhone 3d games & apps development. I try to set background colour for irrlicht scene as transparent, but I can't figure out the way, Below is the code to set Background Color in irrlicht scene:

```
 driver->beginScene(true, true, SColor(0, 255, 255, 255)); // BG colour
```

Is there a way to set BG colour in irrlicht scene transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have an alpha parameter in the function there is no possible way of making a transparent background in irrlicht this way.
The `beginScene()` color is the scene default space color. There is nothing behind it, hence no way of making this color transparent. If you want to add transparent layers to your scene I suggest you use the GUIEnvironment, but this is totally different than the driver->beginScene() approach. You can also use a black background if you want no background color.